# MYSQL query to ignore null values in a delete query

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

**articlesdownloadtrack** with columns - id, articleid, createdtime, modifiedtime

**articles** with columns - id, articlename, articleURL, createdtime, modifiedtime

Some of the entries in articlesdownloadtrack  i.e. **articlesdownloadtrack.articleid** are not available in articles(missed during the process of migration). I want to remove such records.

I am using the query

```
delete from articlesdownloadtrack where articleid not in(select id from articles);
```

But I have to add a constraint to delete only those records whose articleid is not null,  because in articlesdownloadtrack, there are some records whose articleid is NULL, which should not be deleted when this query is executed.

Comment: So add `AND articleid IS NOT NULL`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned @njk , try this :

```
 delete 
     from articlesdownloadtrack 
 where 
    (
     articleid IS NOT NULL AND articleid not in(select id from articles)
    )
```